# Unable to add int into an ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, radix-sort

I am trying to make a Radix Sort algorithm and I have an Array List of Array Lists.

Radix Sort adds elements to the "outer" array list depending on the value of a number's one's, ten's, hundred's, etc. place. Each "inner" array list corresponds to a digit place of 0, 1, 2, 3...9.

The value of variable "base" is 10 as there are 10 digits (0-9)

*Here is the declaration:*

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> digits = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(base); //arraylist that can hold 10 elements to sort elements according to digits 0-9

    for(int i=0; i <digits.size(); i++){

        digits.add(i, new ArrayList<Integer>()); //make an arraylist for each element inside the digits array list, this will hold the numbers that are being sorted
    }
```

However, later when I try to add integers to the correct "inner" array list, I am unable to as I'm trying to add an integer into a place of type ArrayList. I also get an index out of bound error.

```
while(!(lastDigit)) //if last digit has not been reached
    {
        lastDigit = true;

        for(int k=0; k < array.length; k++) //array contains the numbers we are sorting
        {
            number = k / digitPlace; //digitPlace starts off as 1 to first sort by one's place and is then later multiplied by 10 
            int index = number % base; //get digit from correct place

             digits.add(index, k);//line with the ERROR; add the element in the correct place (according to it's digit)

            if(number > 0 && lastDigit) 
            {
                lastDigit = false;
            }

        }
```

The way to solve the problem is that I cast the integer to type ArrayList but that would mean that I would have added an Array List into the inner array list, which is not what I want. I want to add an int into the correct "inner" ArrayList.

Comment: You probably want something like `digits[k].add(idx, number)`; in other words, "add a number to the list at index `k` in the digits list".

Comment: @ggorlen I tried that earlier but I still get the same error even though I would be adding an int into the correct arraylist? The error says "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>"

Comment: In your declaration it will never enter the for-loop. `digits` has no elements so `.size()` will be 0.

Comment: can you explain your aim with an example

Comment: @Ivar Good catch. "Base" would set the capacity but the size would still be 0. I replaced digits.size() with 10 but still same error.

Comment: @NisargPatil basically, what I am trying to do is for example, I have [ [10, 20], [21, 11]... ,[79] ] . That's what the array list would look like when I am sorting numbers with their one's place. Let's say I find another integer "29" in my input array. I would then want to add that to the very last array list but I cannot do that bc I am trying to add an int into ArrayList<Integer>

Answer (score 0):

[JavaDoc of size():](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size())

> Returns the number of elements in this list. (...)

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> digits = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(base);
for(int i=0; i < digits.size(); i++){
    digits.add(i, new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
```

You are referencing the **size** of the List in the for-loop instead of the **capacity**!

Use the *base* variables used for creating the List instead of *digits.size()*

Answer (score 0):

`digits.get(index).add(n);`
where `n` is number from input array that is to be added.

Comment: you might need to incorporate `lastDigit` logic in it

Comment: why index-1? that is creating another out of bounds exception. I had the same statement earlier when I was trying to debug with just index but it was still unsuccessful

Comment: It might be giving you indexOutOfBoundException because, your `digits` is not initialized properly

Comment: `for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
   digits.add(new ArrayList<>());
  }`
Use this to initialize the digits

Comment: Yes, I had already fixed that bc someone pointed it out in the comments above